# What is the default path for sudo command?

Tags: mac, sudo, solaris, aix, hp-ux

What is the default path of `sudo` command? I checked in some Linux flavours and some solaris flavours, it is:

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

If a Solaris machine is not bundled with `sudo`, where will it get installed if we installed it by an external package?

I am developing a discovery script which is common for all Unix-based systems. It will get executed based on the uname command’s output.

To get the machine information without root user, I can create a session using `sudo` command, for that I need the default path of the `sudo` command.

Answer (score 2):

The default path for linux should usually be `/usr/bin/sudo`, but for all unix, or even some customized linux distros, it could really be anywhere (say `/usr/local/bin/sudo`, or even something link `/opt/bin/sudo`, or `/srv/bin/sudo`, etc.)

Assuming it is in your PATH—which it should be— then you should discover it by using which

```
sudocmd=`which sudo`
```

Because the installation prefix on the same distribution could vary, depending on how it is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Use **whereis** to find command location/path

```
$ whereis whereis
sudo: /usr/bin/whereis /usr/share/man/man1/whereis.1.gz
```